# Sharepoint. Show list item version history dialog

Tags: javascript, .net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I have custom page and id of list item. How can i show sharepoint version history dialog from my page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The url format for the version histoy page is:

```
http://<Server>/<WebUrl>/_layouts/versions.aspx?list=<ListID>&ID=<ItemId>&FileName<ServerRelativeFileUrl>
```

Use the SharePoint client API to open the page in a dialog:

```
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.width = 500;
options.height = 250;
options.url = <url>;

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

For a more detailed example you should provide a little more context (does your code run on the server or client; what code do you have so far; etc.)